# Get an ID on page load in jquery script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a PHP while loop where I am generating #id dynamically.

Example :

```
<?php 
$i=1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): 
?>

<tr>
<td class='hashtag' id='status<?php echo $i; ?>'>status value</td>
</tr>

<?php 
$i++;
endwhile: 
?>
```

The status id are generating like this : status1, status2, status3 etc...

I want all these Id's in my JS code ON LOAD for displaying it into the modal dialog.

Example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#status1");
$("#status2");
$("#status3");
.
.
and so on as per the php while loop.

});
</script>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you call them in template using `$('.hashtag').each()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the "[Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector:

```
$('td[id^="status"]').each(function(index){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

You can specify scope of selector in order to target main td's

Comment: $('td[id^="status"]') this will select all td having id started with "status****".you can use $.each() of jquery to deal with each td.Its better to use class instead of id as selector in such cases

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

Change your html

```
<td class='hashtag status'>status value</td>
```

Then the js looks like this:

```
$('.status').each(function(i, el){
    // the i value previously generated in php is here i += 1 if you need it
    i += 1;

    // here is your element. do whatever you want with it:
    $(el).text('I am cell ' + i);
});
```

Comment: No But want only ID's there

Comment: why do you only want ids there? what is wrong with classes? For me it would feel wrong to do this with id's. That's what classes are there for.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td[id^='status']").each(function(el){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

This will give you id of each element.

If you just wish to apply event or plugin, you can do it via -

```
$("td[id^='status']").pluginName();
```

or

```
$("td[id^='status']").on("click",function(){

});
```